# Not able to run meteor in cloud ide, need help to understand meteor memory usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, cloud9-ide, koding

I’m new to both meteor and web frameworks [Core C/C++ developer].
When I tried meteor apps in cloud IDE (both cloud9 and Koding), sample apps runs fine. But, if I add twbs:bootstrap package, the IDE kills meteor (mongodb) due to insufficient memory (Cloud9 has 768MB and Koding provides 1GB).

Also noted that the disk space grows from 60mb initial to some 200+ mb, just for adding one package (twbs:bootstrap).

Hence, I’m not able to proceed further with meteor in cloud. Is it normal that meteor uses this much RAM and disk space? If so, why it uses such huge memory? This wouldn’t be problem for real production web apps?
Please guide me.

Comment: meteor doesn't use a lot of RAM it's probably more of package specific problems, Telescope also doesn't run well on less than 1GB. So it's not normal and I'm not really sure how you can really solve this, But I usually use 1gb of ram instances on DigitalOcean

Comment: Could you please write in to support@c9.io and we'll help get this sorted and working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you install a package, and start Meteor, it tries to update the package and Meteor (if there's a newer version). This can take up a lot more memory than usual. I have been able to get around this by running `meteor update` and then restarting the meteor server. Please note that sometimes even `meteor update` complains of being out of memory, but it should still complete. If it truly runs out of memory, it would say 'Killed' on the terminal. Contact support in this instance.

I have tried using the bootstrap package and have been able to make it work on Cloud9 workspaces using the technique above (Full disclosure, I work at Cloud9). We do try to keep the meteor version up to date due to this issue, but if you have an older workspace, you might still run into this issue each time meteor version increases.

The other thing I've noticed is that memory consumption tends to increase with each hot-reload. If the workspace starts complaining, simply shut the meteor server down and restart it. It should get back to normal levels.

Hope this helps!