# Error When Running Default Meteor App With Bootstrap On Cloud9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, cloud9-ide

Create a default meteor app on Cloud9 (c9.io) IDE, add twbs:bootstrap, & run. Result:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.
```

Below is output from a test project where I created a default app, added bootstrap and run.

```
user:~/workspace $ meteor add twbs:bootstrap                                  
Changes to your project's package version selections:
twbs:bootstrap  added, version 3.3.5   
twbs:bootstrap: The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

user:~/workspace $ meteor --port $IP:$PORT    
[[[[[ ~/workspace ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.                     
Killed
```

After failure, I removed bootstrap from the project and rerun.

```
user:~/workspace $ meteor remove twbs:bootstrap
Changes to your project's package version selections:
twbs:bootstrap  removed from your project
twbs:bootstrap: removed dependency            

user:~/workspace $ meteor --port $IP:$PORT                                                                                                                                                                  
[[[[[ ~/workspace ]]]]]                       
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          
=> App running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

...and meteor project starts up successfully.

Is there a way to get a meteor app running with bootstrap on Cloud9?

Comment: Please check out the advice [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408991/not-able-to-run-meteor-in-cloud-ide-need-help-to-understand-meteor-memory-usage/33672604#33672604)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by [Mutahhir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722657/mutahhir) works.

Run `meteor update` before running your application so that `c9.io` does not run out of memory.